# Какова роль дефиса в словах типа пол-лимона, пол-Москвы?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, словообразование

В наречии ***по-новому*** дефис соединяет приставку с остальной частью слова; в местоимении ***кто-то*** соединяет постфикс с остальной частью слова; в существительном  ***диван-кровать*** — части сложных слов, а в яз. единице ***Москва***-***река*** — разные слова в составе предложения.

Что соединяет дефис в языковых единицах ***пол***-***лимона***, ***пол***-***Москвы*** и подобных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   ... сложные слова с корнем пол
```

В данном случае ответ недостаточен: получается, что дефис соединяет корень и слово в составе сложного существительного?

Единицы типа пол-лимона, пол-Москвы по сути являются словосочетаниями.

Легко заметить, что элемент пол- в подобных единицах тождествен по значению слову половина; ср. пол-лимона и половина лимона, пол-Москвы и половина Москвы. В современном русском языке в слове половина выделяется корень половин-, усеченным вариантом которого и является элемент пол-. Исходя из этого можно предположить, что пол-лимона является либо сложным словом, либо сочетанием слов. **Синтаксическое поведение подобных единиц обнаруживает общие свойства именно со словосочетаниями.**

Если мы возьмем классическое сложное слово, например медбрат, и начнем склонять его, то обнаружим, что оно, во-первых, имеет формы всех падежей и, во-вторых, при изменении по падежам используются окончания, присоединяемые к концу основы: медбрата, медбрату и т. д. При этом окончания слова медбрат полностью совпадают с окончаниями слова брат, в частности в именительном падеже единственного числа оба слова имеют нулевое окончание. Попытавшись просклонять языковую единицу пол-лимона, мы обнаружим, что она имеет только два падежа — именительный и винительный (Осталось пол-лимона; съел пол-лимона), а в контекст других падежей поставить это сочетание не удается: ср. неправильное *отрезал от пол-лимона, *вспомнил о пол-лимона. При этом слово лимон в таком сочетании имеет окончание -а, то есть окончание родительного падежа, а значит, не может выразить значение именительного или винительного падежа. Обратите внимание, что именно в родительном падеже стоит слово лимон в сочетании половина лимона.

При постановке сочетания половина лимона и подобных в нужный падеж изменяется его главное слово: половины лимона, половину лимона и т. д. Неспособность единицы пол-лимона изменяться подобным образом обусловлена свойствами элемента пол-, **не имеющего полного набора форм.**

О том, что пол-лимона — это словосочетание, свидетельствует также существующая в разговорной речи возможность постановки внутрь него прилагательного или местоимения: пол крупного лимона, пол этого лимона.

Таким образом, правильный ответ на поставленный вопрос такой: дефис в словах пол-лимона, пол-Москвы и подобных соединяет разные слова в составе словосочетания. Такой же ответ следует дать и для тех случаев, когда пол- пишется слитно: полдома также является словосочетанием.

Comment: Словосочета́ние — это соединение двух или нескольких самостоятельных слов, связанных по смыслу и грамматически. Слова пол-лимона, полдома не могут быть словосочетанием, так как в русском языке нет САМОМТОЯТЕЛЬНОГО слова "пол".  Слова с корне "пол" ближе всего к сложносокращенным словам вида "Минобороны", завлабораторией. В этих словах сокращено главное слово, которое задает падеж зависимому слову. Поэтому эти формы является НЕСКЛОНЯЕМЫМИ. На сайте Грамота.ру определен статус этих слов.

Comment: Можно найти и самостоятельное употребление -  в диалоге: "Тебе полстакана  или стакан?" -"Пол". Это усечённое слово, как, например, в нашем городе есть Рев. проспект, так и на письмах пишут, это официальное название. Это словосочетание усечённого прилагательного и существительного, все это видят. А насчёт пол-лимона есть разные точки зрения, некоторые учёные не говорят, что это сложное слово, избегают этого термина, говорят "единица языка". Полуслитные написания говорят о связанности и в то же время отдельности понятий. Краса-девица, например, где дефис соединяет сущ. и приложение к нему.

Comment: Как я понимаю, это ваше личное мнение, причем оно расходится с мнением других авторов (например, Грамоты.ру), но вы говорите   следующее:  "правильный ответ на поставленный вопрос такой: дефис в словах пол-лимона... соединяет разные слова в составе словосочетания. Такой же ответ следует дать и для тех случаев, когда пол- пишется слитно". Но при всех разборах в Сети "пол" выделяют как приставку (школьный вариант). В других случаях слова с корнем ПОЛ считают сложными. При решении такого непростого теоретического вопроса желательно рассмотреть все версии и привести ссылки на возможные источники.

Comment: Мы снова говорим о разном. Вы вопрос хорошо прочитали? Кто ж против,что это сложное слово? Только не сложное, а сложносокращённое.И тип словообразования никак не префиксальный, как выходит из Вашего ответа. Это  сложение начальной части слова с целым словом, как и стенгазета, полдыни.Во всех случаях сокращ. слова восходят к словосоч- ям, составным наименованиям. Вот полдень - префиксальный способ, пол - префиксоид, у слова есть формы всех падежей, а полдня - сложение: половина дня. Вы против такой трактовки? А вопрос из олимпиады от университета с Воробьёвых Гор, мы с ученицей участвовали.

Comment: Ссылки тоже можно дать, только вот из серьёзных научных работ на эту тему в Интернете нашлась лишь работа доцента из г.Луцка Пирога, но она приводит мнения других учёных.  http://docplayer.ru/40339105-Semanticheskie-slovoobrazovatelnye-i-orfograficheskie-osobennosti-slov-s-pol-polu.html  Там есть и имя моего преподавателя проф.В.Черепанова.

Answer (score 2):

***Полдома, но пол-лимона.***

С точки зрения грамматики  в обоих случаях это сложные слова с корнем ***пол***

Я могу предположить, что  исключительное дефисное написание связано с выбором **графической формы, удобной для прочтения и понимания смысла слова.**

При написании *пол-лимона* отсутствует двойная согласная ЛЛ, а при написании *пол-арбуза* согласная Л не сливается с последующей гласной.

Написание *пол-Москвы* связано с прописной буквой, которую обычно не принято писать в середине слова

Comment: Но ведь вопрос не об орфографии.

Comment: Про грамматику я тоже ответила: это сложные слова с корнем пол. Из словаря:  ПОЛ-. Первая часть сложных слов.

Comment: Я хотела бы получить точный ответ - продолжение параллельных конструкций в вопросе.

Comment: Вопрос № 264604  
Спасибо за ответ о пол- и полу-. А можно их выделять как корень сложных слов? Ведь в академической грамматике они представлены как словообразовательные компоненты сложных слов (в соответствующем параграфе).
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Да, это возможно.
  Вопрос № 264576  
Какой морфемой являются пол- и полу-? Например, в словах полуденный, полупроводник, полгорода и др.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Справочники и словари обтекаемо называют такие единицы "первыми частями сложных слов". В школе можно считать их и приставками.

Comment: Промежуточный вариант: это префисоид, то есть корень, выступающий в роли приставки

Answer (score 0):

Логика может быть такой: префикс (словообразовательная частица) " пол" - это сокращённая форма существительного "половина",  а в литературе приняты сокращения через дефис. Например: нумиз-ка(нумизматика),  гра-ка(грамматика), нар-сть(народность) и т. д.  Понятно, что эта частица, при определённых условиях, пишется так же и слитно, и раздельно. В данных примерах - именно дефис. Пол-лимона - перед "л",  пол-Москвы - перед собственным именем.

Comment: Значит, пол - это префикс?

Comment: В этом случае - да.  Поскольку это словообразовательная частица( пол-лимона - это не лемон, следовательно - новое слово, образованное при помощи частицы пол, "прикреплённой впереди" (дословный перевод "префикса").  В случае же, когда "пол" пишется раздельно(пол кожаной сумки), оно будет являться количественным числительным, в силу того, что определяет количество и отвечает на вопрос "сколько".

Comment: Спасибо, подождём ещё ответов.