# О загадочном корне ПОЛ-

Tags: словообразование, сложные-слова

Рассмотрим слова *полдома* и *минобороны*: состав, способ образования, классификация (слова взяты для примера).

Продолжение обсуждения вопроса 
 «[Какова роль дефиса в словах типа пол-лимона, пол-Москвы?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447425/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B/447520?noredirect=1#comment457671_447520)»

Слова эти похожи, как близнецы-братья: *половина дома ―
 полдома*, *министерство обороны ― минобороны*.

Хотелось бы узнать:

1. Как образовано слово *минобороны*? Чем оно отличается от *полдома* по составу, способу образования и классификации?
2. Существительные выглядят как несклоняемые. Можно ли определять для них падежи (им. п., в. п.)?
3. *Минобороны* ― это  сложносокращённое слово. Как называются слова с корнем *пол-*? Можно ли их отнести к сложносокращённым, или они считаются сложными словами?
4. Как принято называть формант *пол-*? Это префикс, префиксоид, корень, часть сложного слова или что это? Есть у него официальное общепринятое название?
5. Почему некоторые слова с корнем *пол-* пишутся через дефис?

---

**Примечание**

Я уважаю труд учёных, как его не уважать? Но, к сожалению, наука не всегда спешит решить практические вопросы. В то же время есть определённая группа пользователей языка (школьники, студенты), которые особенно заинтересованы в точных, ясных и логичных ответах на разные темы. Им же экзамены сдавать!

Вспомним ещё раз ответы Грамоты.ру:

> **Вопрос № 264604**    Спасибо за ответ о пол- и полу-. **А можно их выделять как корень сложных слов?** Ведь в академической грамматике они представлены как словообразовательные компоненты сложных слов (в соответствующем параграфе).
>   *Ответ справочной службы русского языка*
>   **Да, это возможно**.
>
> **Вопрос № 264576**    Какой морфемой являются пол- и полу-? Например, в словах полуденный, полупроводник, полгорода и др.
>   *Ответ справочной службы русского языка.*
>   Справочники и словари **обтекаемо** называют такие единицы "**первыми частями сложных слов**". В школе можно считать их и **приставками**.

Как говорится, без комментариев.

Answer (score 2):

Минобороны - слово полученное аббревиацией, сокращением слова (и является именем собственным в общем случае). Таким образом, оно слабо связано с сложными словами начинающимися с морфемы пол, полу.

Если подходить формально, то они являются корневыми морфемами с слабо определенной ролью, обозначающими либо не**пол**ное действие - `я пишу этот текст полулежа на кресле`, либо **пол**овину чего-либо. А именно в зависимости от использования может быть приставкой или корнем. Отсюда пол-литра, но
поллитровка. Второе можно считаль сложным словом. К тому же, правило намеренно обходит его и ему подобные, оговаривая родительный падеж для слов с написанием через дефис (Розенталь. Орфография русского языка, пар.41).

В случае второго зачения, половины чего-либо - *пол* считается числительным. Можно еще вспомнить, что существует случай раздельного написания, например, пол учебного года.

Написание слов, в отличие от их употребления и происхождения, имеет более условную природу. Сущесвующие правила связаны с нормами, созданными для упрощения чтения текста и стандартизации написания, а не с происхождением слов.